# Bulk Update start date based on previous end date

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I am trying to do a bulk update on a table with about 700K records in it.  I need to update the effective start date with the effective end date of the previous record.  I am having trouble with the performance on the update statement when using the sub query.  It is taking over an hour to run even with a filter on date (7/1/2016-7/15/2016 which is around 2k records).  I tried it in as a simple update statement, as an insert, and in a loop.  The explain plan using ROWID instead of account_dim_key (PK on the table) is much more optimal however, I get an error that the subquery returns more than one row.  I am not sure why that is happening with the ROWID.

ID is natural key on table, account_dim_key is PK and unique.  Both are indexed.  Table is a type 2 SCD.

1. How can I modify the update statement using ROWID
2. Would it be more optimal to use a FORALL update and if so how would i write that (new to pl sql and unfamliar with arrays)

Update statement using ROWID which returns error single row subquery returns more than one row but with optimal explain plan

```
UPDATE DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA
   SET effective_end_dt =
          (SELECT prev_dt
             FROM (SELECT LAG (
                             effective_end_dt,
                             1,
                             effective_start_dt)
                          OVER (PARTITION BY account_dim_key
                                ORDER BY effective_start_dt)
                             AS prev_dt,
                          ROWID AS rid
                     FROM dexwhs.d_account_veeva ac2) a
            WHERE a.rid = ROWID)
```

Update statement using acocunt_dim_key with not optimal explain plan

```
UPDATE DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA
   SET effective_end_dt =
          (SELECT prev_dt
             FROM (SELECT LAG (
                             effective_end_dt,
                             1,
                             effective_start_dt)
                          OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                ORDER BY effective_start_dt, account_dim_key)
                             AS prev_dt,
                          account_dim_key AS rid
                     FROM dexwhs.d_account_veeva ac2) a
            WHERE a.rid = account_dim_key)
```

Update with loop

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PREV_UPDT
IS
   CURSOR c1
   IS
        SELECT account_dim_key,
               id,
               active_flag,
               effective_end_dt,
               effective_start_dt,
               created_date,
               last_modified_date,
               (SELECT prev_dt
                  FROM (SELECT LAG (
                                  effective_end_dt,
                                  1,
                                  effective_start_dt)
                               OVER (
                                  PARTITION BY id
                                  ORDER BY effective_start_dt, account_dim_key)
                                  AS prev_dt,
                               account_dim_key AS rid
                          FROM dexwhs.d_account_veeva ac2) a
                 WHERE a.rid = src.account_dim_key)
          FROM dexwhs.d_account_veeva src
      ORDER BY id, effective_start_dt, account_dim_key;
   r1   c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;

   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO r1;

      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('id=' || r1.id);

      UPDATE dexwhs.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA trgt
         SET trgt.effective_start_dt = r1.prev_date,
             trgt.audit_last_update_dt = SYSDATE,
       WHERE trgt.account_dim_key = r1.account_dim_key;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('r1.id_found');
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c1;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `account_dim_key` is primary key, then try `MERGE`

```
MERGE INTO dexwhs.d_account_veeva a
USING (
   SELECT  account_dim_key,
           LAG ( effective_end_dt, 1, effective_start_dt)
           OVER (PARTITION BY account_dim_key
                 ORDER BY effective_start_dt)
           AS prev_dt
   FROM dexwhs.d_account_veeva
) b
ON (a.account_dim_key  = b.account_dim_key )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.effective_end_dt = b.prev_dt
```

The query must take some time since it is updating the whole table.
Perhaps You can speed `LAG ... (PARTITION BY account_dim_key ORDER BY effective_start_dt)` part up using a composite index on `(account_dim_key, effective_start_dt)` columns.

```
CREATE INDEX some_name 
ON dexwhs.d_account_veeva(account_dim_key, effective_start_dt)
```

however Oracle can ignore this index and prefer full table scan because the subquery is against the whole table.